# Wordpress Transfer Broke CSS - Images + Links Work

Tags: mysql, css, html, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am having a rather weird problem transferring this website to its new server ( same domain name , new host ). The website is not loading the layout / css properly to display the page. www.chi-ri.org - as you could image, all these menus text and images are suppoes to be aligned nicely and uniform. It is displaying everything almost completely vertically.
Here is what I did.

-Backup entire wordpress directory on website

-Export SQL file via phpmyadmin

-Create new server

-Import all files - set wp-config to match DB settings

-Import MySQL export to new server via phpmyadmin

From here I get this broken layout. Any thoughts on what would be making this happen? Like stated in the Title, the links and images are all there and working, just not the layout.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Import MySQL export to new server via phpmyadmin` if it works up to this point are you overwritting some of the settings stored in the db?

Comment: I have tried this without any luck - Doing both uploading the WP-database first and also uploading the wp files first. The result ends up being the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like your problem is within the "themes" folder.

If i call http://chi-ri.org/wp-content/themes/ i get a 500 Internal Server Error, but calling http://chi-ri.org/wp-content/uploads/ gives me a 403 Forbidden (which probably happens, because Directory Indexes are off, so everything ok here). Calling any (nonexistent) file inside the themes folder (http://chi-ri.org/wp-content/themes/nonexistent.file) also gives me an error 500, whereas calling a nonexistent file in uploads (http://chi-ri.org/wp-content/uploads/nonexistent.file) gives me a 404 Not found error, which I would expect.

My first guess in this case is, the error is caused by a .htaccess file in the themes folder or some wrong Apache Directives messing with the themes folder in upstream .htaccess files. Check for redirection loops or aliases causing permission conflicts. Also check permissions on the themes folder itself.

Comment: Bravo sir - I can't believe the problem was that simple...

Like you said, there was a weird .htaccess file in the theme folder that I COMPLETELY overlooked... Deleted that nasty thing and everythings back to normal.

THANKYOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear such positive feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It appears one of your stylesheets is not loading:
http://chi-ri.org/wp-content/themes/2010-weaver/style.css

With the `500 Internal` error there, assuming the file is in that location on your server, my guess is that you have a permissions/ownership issue. If the file isn't there, it might be a good place to start to get a fix.

Comment: The file is in that location and I have just set the permission on the file to 775 but nothing has changed.
I may see a problem now though - the website in my VPS is under /www/wp-content/themes/2010-weaver/style.css - Im not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: You might also need to check owner/group of the file. Assuming you have SSH access, can you do an `ls -lah` and see if the owner/group is different than the rest of your files?

Comment: all ownerships are under root, which is fine - and I reset all file permissions to reccomended by wordpress, no changes.

Comment: Is the problem that it is looking for a folder called chi-ri.org in my VPS and I do not actually have this folder? its under var/www/wp-content If I changed the folder "Www" to "chi-ri.org" would that make it work?

Comment: Sorry for third comment but I just tried changing the link to under header.php to where the css file actually is without any luck as well.

Comment: Have you checked your log files? Maybe that will yield a clue as to where the file should be located. I noticed you have some htaccess or apache config that blocks access to wp-admin (this is good, but I'm wondering if your .htaccess or config file have an error in them). When trying to access chi-ri.org/wp-content/themes I get the same 500 error, which I don't think should be the case. Maybe try some of the things found on this page: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/

Comment: Ran through all of these suggestions on the suggested website, All of this has already been set in place and what's not has been done. No errors in .htaccess or wp-config.php . 

Do you think it could be a problem with any MySQL tables or reference to style sheets because during the server to server transfer, the folder structure has definitely changed. Like I said there is no longer chi-ri.org/wp-content - that has changed to var/www/wp-content/themes/2010-weaver/style.css on the new server. Is there a reference problem happening that I am overlooking?

Comment: It also is probably worth mentioning that on my dashboard under appearance > themes , there are no thumbnails showing for each theme like it normally does. This happened as soon as I moved over the server files and I am positive the files are correct.

Comment: This is not a fix, but it may help narrow some things down. Try placing this bit of code in your `wp-config.php` file - http://pastebin.com/FZqthZj3 below the line that says `/* That's all ... */`. This will tell WordPress to serve files from where you access it. This can yield a helpful result when dealing with this kind of issue. If that "resolves" the issue, then it will tell us that it is definitely a relative path issue.

Comment: Also, the path is typically `/var/www/` not `var/www/`. It could be as simple as fixing that. `/var/www/` is where many Linux Apache web-roots are.

Comment: First off, thanks so much michael for helping me out, extremely appreciated.

I added that bit of code into my wp-config and nothing has happened, no layout changes , no errors fixed. So this must mean the problem is completely different.

Where to go from here - going to be searching for the answer all day. 
Cheers

Comment: No problem. Have you had any success today?

Comment: No success with anything - I am at a loss

Answer (score 0):

off hand -

1. go to wp settings and set permalinks to postname and save.
2. Run phpinfo() on your index page - is mod rewrite enabled?
3. Check your folders with your ftp program - directories should be 755
4. rename your .htaccess file
5. double check your config settings
6. try an fresh install

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run phpinfo() on your index page - is mod rewrite enabled?
Check your folders with your ftp program - directories should be 755. Rename your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

weird problem transferring this website to its new server ( same domain name , new host ). The website is not loading the layout / css properly to display the page. www.chi-ri.org - as you could image, all these menus text and images are suppoes to be aligned nicely and uniform. It is displaying everything almost completely vertically. Here is what I did.

Comment: What did you do? Code sample?

Answer (score 0):

rename your .htaccess file
double check your config settings
try an fresh install